# Exporting Multiple range to a txt file

Tags: excel, vba

I need to export multiple ranges from different worksheet in to a single text file I want the the cell ranges to append one after another. Currently I'm using this code which works perfectly for one range one worksheet what do I need to modify this to make it work with more ranges?

Example ranges I would like to add

```
Sheet1 A2:E50
Sheet2 A2:F60
Sheet4 A2:C45
```

Current code

```
Sub Export()
Dim r As Range, c As Range
Dim sTemp As String

Open Workbooks("Test.xlsm").Path & "\Test.SQL" For Output As #1
For Each r In Worksheets("SQL1").Range("A1:D50").Rows
    sTemp = ""
    For Each c In r.Cells
        sTemp = sTemp & c.Text & Chr(9)
    Next c

    'Get rid of trailing tabs
    While Right(sTemp, 1) = Chr(9)
        sTemp = Left(sTemp, Len(sTemp) - 1)
    Wend
    Print #1, sTemp
Next r
Close #1
End Sub
```

Comment: Here is an alternative way to do it... Copy the relevant ranges to a new workbook and then save that workbook as csv?

Comment: already thought of that and its not really viable considering theres about 10,000 rows of cells im exporting which is the reason I need to really get this code modified

Comment: All the more reason then to do it via the approach I mentioned :) Much better than looping though 10000 rows of cells? ;)

Comment: Let me show you an example

Comment: This is just a small part of a much bigger project and it will not work for me having another workbook with all that information stored when it doesnt need to be, when I can just have one bit of code that can do the job

Comment: Oops, I just saw your comment. I already posted an example

Comment: BTW, your one bit of code will take ages to finish if you have 10000 rows of data like you mentioned. The method specified by me will not take more than 5 seconds...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like I mentioned in the above comment this is the fastest way you can export those ranges to text file. No looping required...

**Untested**

```
Dim Thiswb As Workbook, thatWb As Workbook

Sub Sample()
    Set Thiswb = ThisWorkbook
    Set thatWb = Workbooks.Add

    CopyRange Thiswb.Sheets("Sheet1"), Thiswb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:E10000")
    CopyRange Thiswb.Sheets("Sheet2"), Thiswb.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:F10000")
    CopyRange Thiswb.Sheets("Sheet3"), Thiswb.Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A1:C10000")

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    thatWb.SaveAs "C:\Temp.csv", xlCSV
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub

Sub CopyRange(ws As Worksheet, rng As Range)
    Dim lRow As Long

    lRow = thatWb.Sheets(1).Range("A" & thatWb.Sheets(1).Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    rng.Copy thatWb.Sheets(1).Range("A" & lRow)
End Sub
```

Followup from comments

> Siddharth this is usful but wont work for me, as my above code plugs in to SQL and JAVA, can you show me how to modify my above code to perform multipul ranges on different sheet regardless of this been the best methord, unfortunatly im not very good with VBA :( –  Windmill 5 mins ago

Is this what you are trying? (**Untested**)

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim Thiswb As Workbook
    Set Thiswb = ThisWorkbook

    Export Thiswb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:E50")
    Export Thiswb.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2:F60")
    Export Thiswb.Sheets("Sheet4").Range("A2:C45")
End Sub

Sub Export(rng As Range)
    Dim r As Range, c As Range
    Dim sTemp As String

    '~~> Use Append instead of Output
    Open Workbooks("Test.xlsm").Path & "\Test.SQL" For Append As #1

    For Each r In rng.Rows
        sTemp = ""
        For Each c In r.Cells
            sTemp = sTemp & c.Text & Chr(9)
        Next c

        'Get rid of trailing tabs
        While Right(sTemp, 1) = Chr(9)
            sTemp = Left(sTemp, Len(sTemp) - 1)
        Wend
        Print #1, sTemp
    Next r
    Close #1
End Sub
```

Comment: Siddharth this is usful but wont work for me, as my above code plugs in to SQL and JAVA, can you show me how to modify my above code to perform multipul ranges on different sheet regardless of this been the best methord, unfortunatly im not very good with VBA :(

Comment: When I run the sample code it errors at this line -> Open Workbooks("Test.xlsm").Path & "\Test.SQL" For Append As #1

Comment: What does `Workbooks("Test.xlsm").Path & "\Test.SQL"` give you? Can you debug it?

Comment: I not really good with VBA including the debugger, other than telling you I get a run time error 9 and it stopping at that line im not really sure what else to look at?

Comment: Type `Msgbox Workbooks("Test.xlsm").Path & "\Test.SQL"` before the line `Open Workbooks("Test.xlsm").Path & "\Test.SQL" For Append As #1` and tell me what do you get?

Comment: Seems to me that you do not have a workbook "Test" open. Or if it is open then it is in a separate excel instance :)

Comment: No the code is in the same workbook as the Text.xlsm, I get Expression:Append value:<Expression not defined in context> Type:Empty Context:Export.Export

Comment: It works for me... What happens if you replace it with `Thisworkbook.Path & "\Test.SQL"`